# Checking values between individual elements in two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, splice

I am trying to remove specific elements from an array based on data I'm getting from an API. The API returns an array of objects like this {"videoDate":"07/31/2020","videoTime":"1:00 AM"}. I have an existing array with items that look like this "07/31/2020 1:00 AM". My intention is to check if the existing array contains an item with a string matching both the videoDate and videoTime strings from the object and remove them.

```
        let responseArray = JSON.parse(response);
        dayArray.forEach((day) => {
          responseArray.forEach((res) => {
            if (day === res.videoTime) { 
              console.log('match');
              let index = dayArray.indexOf(day);
              dayArray.splice(index, 1);
            }
          })
        })
```

The above code is removing every element from the `dayArray`. For context, the `response` contains ~50 identical objects `[{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"}` for testing. The day array contains 30 strings all with the same format but different values. There is one string in this array with the exact value of `"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"`. My intention is to have the function delete this entry and leave all the remaining ones to verify that it is working. Right now it is removing every element from the `dayArray`.

EDIT:

This is what the dayArray initially looks like before the function is run:

```
["07/31/2020 1:00 AM", "08/06/2020 9:00AM", "08/06/2020 10:00AM", "08/06/2020 11:00AM", "08/06/2020 1:00PM", "08/10/2020 9:00AM", "08/10/2020 10:00AM", "08/10/2020 11:00AM", "08/10/2020 1:00PM", "08/11/2020 9:00AM", "08/11/2020 10:00AM", "08/11/2020 11:00AM", "08/11/2020 1:00PM", "08/12/2020 9:00AM", "08/12/2020 10:00AM", "08/12/2020 11:00AM", "08/12/2020 1:00PM", "08/13/2020 9:00AM", "08/13/2020 10:00AM", "08/13/2020 11:00AM", "08/13/2020 1:00PM", "08/17/2020 9:00AM", "08/17/2020 10:00AM", "08/17/2020 11:00AM", "08/17/2020 1:00PM", "08/18/2020 9:00AM", "08/18/2020 10:00AM", "08/18/2020 11:00AM", "08/18/2020 1:00PM"]
```

The API response looks like this.

```
[{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splicing the array that you're iterating over will not work, because all the array indexes move down and the iteration skips the element that moves into the place it just checked.

Use `filter()` instead.

```js
let dayArray = ["07/31/2020 1:00 AM", "08/06/2020 9:00AM", "08/06/2020 10:00AM", "08/06/2020 11:00AM", "08/06/2020 1:00PM", "08/10/2020 9:00AM", "08/10/2020 10:00AM", "08/10/2020 11:00AM", "08/10/2020 1:00PM", "08/11/2020 9:00AM", "08/11/2020 10:00AM", "08/11/2020 11:00AM", "08/11/2020 1:00PM", "08/12/2020 9:00AM", "08/12/2020 10:00AM", "08/12/2020 11:00AM", "08/12/2020 1:00PM", "08/13/2020 9:00AM", "08/13/2020 10:00AM", "08/13/2020 11:00AM", "08/13/2020 1:00PM", "08/17/2020 9:00AM", "08/17/2020 10:00AM", "08/17/2020 11:00AM", "08/17/2020 1:00PM", "08/18/2020 9:00AM", "08/18/2020 10:00AM", "08/18/2020 11:00AM", "08/18/2020 1:00PM"];
let responseArray = [{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"},{"videoTime":"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"}];

dayArray = dayArray.filter(date_time => !responseArray.find(({videoTime}) => videoTime == date_time));
console.log(dayArray);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. On the line where you define the variable, it is crashing with the error `TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`

Comment: That means the regular expression isn't matching the data. Are there values in `dayArray` that don't match the pattern?

Comment: I've made the regexp more flexible, and added error checking.

Comment: Yes actually the dayArray had slightly different formats than the example I gave. I changed it so that they all had the same format but the invalid date still remains in the array

Comment: I've edited the post to better show what is happening

Comment: That makes things easier, there's no need to parse the date and time, since the values in the objects are in the same format.